# HTTP Request fail

Tags: android

I have to get an HTTP request like this:

```
http://www.aroundertouch.com/queriesandroid1dot0/project/idProjet/45.484171;;9.050393;;Rotondi Group S.R.L. - Costruzione Macchine Abbigliamento/iphone/354781043339495/lang/en_US
```

With this code:

```
url = new URL(query);
   Log.d(TAG,url.toString());
      connection = url.openConnection();
      httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)connection; 
      int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode(); 
      // HTTP status okay
      if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { 
       // preparo stream 
       in = httpConnection.getInputStream();
       DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
       DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
       dom = db.parse(in);      
      }
      // HTTP status fail 
      else{
       throw new Exception("responseCode != 200 OK in "+query);
      }
      in.close();
      httpConnection.disconnect();
      _ret = parseXML(dom);
```

I meet this exception and I suspect that it is caused by an not encoded URL, how can I encode my URL? It isn't automatically encoded by HTTPURLConnection?
Excpetion:

```
D/dalvikvm(10100): GC freed 3447 objects / 513168 bytes in 47ms
W/System.err(10100): org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected end of document
W/System.err(10100):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:129)
W/System.err(10100):    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:157)
W/System.err(10100):    at granet.arounder.webservice.ThreadDatiCard.doInBackground(ThreadDatiCard.java:76)
W/System.err(10100):    at granet.arounder.webservice.ThreadDatiCard.doInBackground(ThreadDatiCard.java:1)
W/System.err(10100):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
W/System.err(10100):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
W/System.err(10100):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
W/System.err(10100):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
W/System.err(10100):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
W/System.err(10100):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the data in your URL contains spaces which is bad and probably causing your request to not return what you are expecting to parse, use the built in urlencoder.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: Indeed. You probably get a HTML file back.